# Simple Graph |V|= 10^6, degree 4: Maximum Independent Subset?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

You are given a simple graph of max degree 4 with 1 million vertices.

We want to find a Maximum Independent Subset.

In the general case it is NP hard.

Does the fact that the degree is max 4 provide an efficient solution to calculate it?

Comment: You mean this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: @DennisMeng: Yes thanks, I have updated the question to use correct terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading further into that Wikipedia page, I found this on the subject:

> For instance, for sparse graphs (graphs in which the number of edges
>   is at most a constant times the number of vertices in any subgraph),
>   the maximum clique has bounded size and may be found exactly in linear
>   time;<sup>[6]</sup> however, for the same classes of graphs, or even
>   for the more restricted class of bounded degree graphs, finding the
>   maximum independent set is MAXSNP-complete, implying that, for some
>   constant c (depending on the degree) it is NP-hard to find an
>   approximate solution that comes within a factor of c of the
>   optimum.<sup>[7]</sup>

Your case is the bounded degree case, so judging from this snippet, your more restrictive version is still NP-hard.

Comment: This is because a maximum independent set in a graph is equivalent to a maximal clique in the complement of the graph (the graph with exactly the set of edges missing from the first graph). If one is bounded, the other is not.

Comment: The reference [5] can be found by a Google search and it shows independent set is already MAXSNP-complete for graphs of degree 3.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very simple greedy 1/5-approximation. Take any vertex, add it to independent set, and remove neighbours from the graph. Continue till no vertices remain. A bit more general version of this trick is [Turan's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_conditional_probabilities#Example_using_pessimistic_estimators).

Comment: If you read on in that Wikipedia page, it cites a reference saying that if you choose the lowest-degree vertex instead of just an arbitrary one, you get within a factor of 2.